# What is LS0... encoding of a PKI certificate?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, encoding, pem

I am looking through a set of PKI certificates and key strings that are specified in a kubernetes yaml file. They are used for testing. Some of the strings are keyed (as in yaml key-value) as `crt.pem`. All of the strings have the following form:

`LS0...`

The typical encoding that I have seen for .pem files is ASCII base64 and begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.

Does someone know what this encoding is?

Edit: grammar & phrasing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that this is just base64 encoded PEM:

```
$ echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" | base64
LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCg==

$ echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" | base64 | cut -c-3
LS0
```